# FilterExpression to get items a fields array is not empty in dynamoDb using javascript

Tags: javascript, amazon-dynamodb, filterexpression

Please any idea how i can filter this sample dynamodb table to return only results where atleast one of the field "old" or "new" array is not empty, in the sample table below it should return the items with id "2" and "3".

Table:
field name = item

```
[
  {
    id: "1",
    product: {"new": [], "old": []},
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    product: {"new": [{name: "a"}], "old": [name: "a"]},
  },
  {
    id: "3",
    product: {"new": [], "old": [name: "a"]},
  },
]
```

i want the filter to be similar to this:

```
FilterExpression: 'isTest = :boolean',
ExpressionAttributeValues: { ':boolean': isTest },
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that each item in your list is an individual item in your table, then you can achieve your use-case using a `Scan` and the following `FilterExpression`:

```
aws dynamodb scan \
--table-name <tablename> \
--filter-expression 'size(#v.#o) > :num OR size(#v.#n) > :num' \
--expression-attribute-names '{"#v": "product", "#o": "old", "#n":"new"}' \
--expression-attribute-values '{":num":{"N":"0"}}'
```

Using [`size`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.OperatorsAndFunctions.html#Expressions.OperatorsAndFunctions.Functions) filter function:

> If the attribute is of type List or Map, size returns the number of child elements.
> Example: Check whether the number of OneStar reviews has exceeded a certain threshold. The expression attribute value :v_sub is a placeholder for 3.
> `size(ProductReviews.OneStar) > :v_sub`